# this, these, that, those, diese, das relationship

Tags: translation, english-to-german, pronoun

I haven't seen any corresponding translation in German for **this, these, that, those**. Instead, there are both **diese** and **das** being used as pronoun and both seem to be used for both plural and singular objects placed at different distances.

However, I get confused when deciding **das** or **diese** should be used to refer to an object. **Das** is normally an article, but does it mean **this** and **that** as well? **Diese** also have the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"der, die, das" can be three things in German:

1. A definite article - "the"

   > Der Mann geht die Strasse entlang.
   >
   > Die Frau geht auf dem Gehweg.
   >
   > Das Mädchen spielt auf dem Spielplatz.
2. A demonstrative pronoun "that", "this"

   > **Der** Mann da geht die Strasse entlang.
   >
   > **Die** Frau dort geht auf dem Gehweg.
   >
   > **Das** Mädchen da hinten spielt auf dem Spielplatz.
3. A relative pronoun "which", "that"

   > Der Mann, der die Strasse entlanggeht, trägt ein gelbes Hemd.
   >
   > Die Frau, die auf dem Gehweg geht, ist grade fast gestolpert.
   >
   > Das Mädchen, das auf dem Spielplatz spielt, scheint Spaß zu haben.

The plural is "die" in all three cases.

Which is which can only be determined by context.

"dieser, diese, dieses", on the other hand, is always a demonstrative pronoun, thus a synonym for (2) only. This demonstrative pronoun has a counterpart in German, just like "this" has "that" in English, to be able to vary qording based on distance. This counterpart, always meaning "that", is "*jener, jene, jenes*"

Comment: Relationship with plurals are missing in the explanation. It would be better to have them as well.

Comment: When you say **das** ist ein Buch, you need to know article of the object which you don't know what it is. This sounds very strange in case of a demonstrative pronoun. According to your explanation, **Das** ist der Mann is false, but **der** ist der Mann is correct. Have I understood it correct?

Comment: Sort of. If you are pointing to a thing you don't know, it's hard to know the article beforehand. You always use "das" in this case, then. So, assume you identify a burglar at the Police station, you could both say "**Das** war der Mann, der die Bank überfallen hat" and "**Der** war es, der die Bank überfallen hat". Beware, this works only for demonstrative usage.

Comment: Can I also use **diese** instead of using **das**? ***Das** ist ein Buch vs **dieses** ist ein Buch?

Comment: The answer is the last paragraph - yes, if the usage of "das" is demonstrative.